# How to crate random data for the struct in julia?

Tags: struct, julia

I have created a structure, txn:

```
struct txn
    txn_id::Int64
    bank::String
    branch::String
    teller::String
    customer::String
    account::String
    timestamp::DateTime
    dr_cr::String
    amount::Float64
end
```

Please guide me in creating random data for the struct!

**Update 1:**

With reference to Professor Bogumił Kamiński's advice, adding domains of fields as follows:

```
a) txn_id is a unique integer(auto incrementing)
b) bank is a 20 character Legal Entity Identifier
c) branch is a 8 or 11 character Business Identifier Codes(SWIFT-BIC)
d) teller is a 9 digit Social Security Number
e) customer is a 9 digit Social Security Number or a 20 character Legal Entity Identifier
f) account is an 34 character International Bank Account Number(IBAN)
g) timestamp is a iso8601 date-time.
h) dr_cr is in (dr, cr)
i) amount > 0.0000
```

Comment: I will comment on what I think is a good strategy for generating such a structure in an answer.

Comment: Since some of your fields are very specific, like the IBAN and BIC, I think you're better off creating a separatate type for them so you can ensure constraints both in construction and random generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not specified precisely enough, as "random" is an ambiguous term, therefore what you ask for does not have a single solution.

In general if you say "random" you should specify the domain and the distribution over this domain. Given this here is a solution that automatically detects field types of the struct and populates them with uniform pseudorandom samples from prespecified domains.

```
using Dates

domains = Dict(Int => 1:10,
               String => string.('a':'z'),
               DateTime => DateTime("2019-01-01"):Day(1):DateTime("2019-05-30"))

struct Txn
    txn_id::Int64
    bank::String
    branch::String
    teller::String
    customer::String
    account::String
    timestamp::DateTime
    dr_cr::String
    amount::Int64
end

Txn_rand() = Txn(map(t -> rand(domains[t]), fieldtypes(Txn))...)
```

And now you can write:

```
julia> Txn_rand()
Txn(3, "q", "f", "j", "m", "z", 2019-03-10T00:00:00, "c", 1)

julia> Txn_rand()
Txn(8, "e", "o", "m", "l", "z", 2019-04-05T00:00:00, "p", 5)

julia> Txn_rand()
Txn(3, "k", "u", "c", "z", "y", 2019-03-13T00:00:00, "x", 1)
```

**EDIT**

Given the comment here is how I would approach the generation of the `Txn` structure (you can probably be more specific e.g. by giving a closed list of `bank` and `branch` values etc. as you probably have it - then use the approach proposed above):

```
using Dates, Random

global TXN_ID_COUNTER = 1

function Txn_rand()
    global TXN_ID_COUNTER += 1
    Txn(TXN_ID_COUNTER,
        randstring('A':'Z', 20),
        randstring('A':'Z', rand(Bool) ? 8 : 11),
        rand(Bool) ? randstring('1':'9', 9) : randstring('A':'Z', 20),
        randstring('1':'9', 9),
        randstring('A':'Z', 2) * randstring('1':'9', 32),
        rand(DateTime("2019-01-01"):Second(1):DateTime("2019-05-30")),
        rand(["dr", "cr"]),
        rand(1:100000) / 10000
       )
end
```

I also omit validation of the generated fields (which in general you could do as some of them have validation rules).