# How to create dataframe from struct instances?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Referring, Professor Bogumił Kamiński's answer at, [How to crate random data for the struct in julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376734/how-to-crate-random-data-for-the-struct-in-julia) to create random transactions:

```
using Dates, Random
    
struct Txn
    txn_id::Int64
    bank::String
    branch::String
    teller::String
    customer::String
    account::String
    timestamp::DateTime
    dr_cr::String
    amount::Float64
end

###a) txn_id is a unique integer(auto incrementing)
###b) bank is a 20 character Legal Entity Identifier
###c) branch is a 8 or 11 character Business Identifier Codes(SWIFT-BIC)
###d) teller is a 9 digit Social Security Number
###e) customer is a 9 digit Social Security Number or a 20 character Legal Entity Identifier
###f) account is an 34 character International Bank Account Number(IBAN)
###g) timestamp is a iso8601 date-time.
###h) dr_cr is in (dr, cr)
###i) amount > 0.0000

global TXN_ID_COUNTER = 0

function Txn_rand()
    global TXN_ID_COUNTER += 1
    Txn(TXN_ID_COUNTER,
        randstring('A':'Z', 20),
        randstring('A':'Z', rand(Bool) ? 8 : 11),
        rand(Bool) ? randstring('1':'9', 9) : randstring('A':'Z', 20),
        randstring('1':'9', 9),
        randstring('A':'Z', 2) * randstring('1':'9', 32),
        rand(DateTime("2019-01-01"):Second(1):DateTime("2019-05-30")),
        rand(["dr", "cr"]),
        rand(1:100000) / 10000
       )
end

for i in 1:10000
println(Txn_rand())
end
```

Please guide me in creating dataframe from struct Txn instances created using the Txn_rand()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have shortened Txn to 4 fields to make this less cluttered but it works in your full example.

```
julia> xs = [Txn(rand(Int), now(), "blah", rand()) for _ = 1:10]
10-element Vector{Txn}:
 Txn(3172994130001029138, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.6911078993055448)
 Txn(5553892348254201766, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.8135795608580065)
 Txn(6446596849808094820, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.9574132952694803)
 Txn(-5951838352334406764, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.7028103184480696)
 Txn(380529577856060513, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.466877054993605)
 Txn(-155547378735377549, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.012196709644630266)
 Txn(-1712160832012638847, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.7808857491803258)
 Txn(-2936285901483110933, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.17976924207033895)
 Txn(-3542439204419290447, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.7616012818389677)
 Txn(1244040602766760111, DateTime("2021-08-14T14:25:03.917"), "blah", 0.7688352803270522)

julia> DataFrame(Dict(n=>[getfield(x, n) for x in xs] for n in fieldnames(Txn)))
10×4 DataFrame
 Row │ amount     dr_cr   timestamp                txn_id               
     │ Float64    String  DateTime                 Int64                
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.691108   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917   3172994130001029138
   2 │ 0.81358    blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917   5553892348254201766
   3 │ 0.957413   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917   6446596849808094820
   4 │ 0.70281    blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917  -5951838352334406764
   5 │ 0.466877   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917    380529577856060513
   6 │ 0.0121967  blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917   -155547378735377549
   7 │ 0.780886   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917  -1712160832012638847
   8 │ 0.179769   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917  -2936285901483110933
   9 │ 0.761601   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917  -3542439204419290447
  10 │ 0.768835   blah    2021-08-14T14:25:03.917   1244040602766760111
```

One comment I have is that you should really try to avoid this if possible. When you have many structs, different fields of each struct are packed together in memory, making it very efficient to loop over each `Txn`. By re-structure them into a DataFrame, you not only have to copy bytes all over the places, now looping over rows is less efficient because different entries in the same row are not together in memory.